# How to make fragment animation swipeable

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I want to have a swipable layout with card flip animations in between.
So far I've made one with a fragment and two buttons, when I click on one, it animates to the next or previous with flip. 
Is it possible to do it with swipes and make the buttons obsolete?(Something to do with Viewpager maybe?)

Comment: FragmentViewPager from the v4 SupportLibrary is what you're after. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: Perhaps it can be combined with Jazzy View Pager to supply the flip animation, I've not tried - https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with a `ViewPager.PageTransformer`:

```
public class FlipPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        if(position >= -0.5 && position <= 0.5) {
            page.setAlpha(1);
        } else {
            page.setAlpha(0);
        }

        if(position >= -1 && position <= 1) {
            page.setTranslationX(page.getWidth() * -position);
            page.setRotationY(position * 180);
        }
    }

}
```

Then apply the `PageTransformer` to a `ViewPager`:

```
mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new FlipPageTransformer());
```